# I cannot read my state from another component (Redux)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue about reading my state from another component. I use Redux Toolkit to store my state.

**colorPick.js :**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const colorizerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'colorizer',
  initialState: {
    color: { nav: '#cecece',
             bg: '#ebebeb' }
  },
  reducers: {
    yellow: state => {
      state.color = { nav: '#e1ce00',
                      bg: '#ffed27' }
    },
    red: state => {
      state.color = { nav: '#e11300',
                      bg: '#ff3d27' }
    },
    green: state => {
      state.color = { nav: '#00e104',
                      bg: '#4bff27' }
    },
    pink: state => {
      state.color = { nav: '#e100ce',
                      bg: '#ff27fb' }
    },
    orange: state => {
      state.color = { nav: '#e18b00',
                      bg: '#ff8527' }
    },
    // incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
    //   state.value += action.payload
    // }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { yellow,
               red,
               green,
               pink,
               orange, } = colorizerSlice.actions

export default colorizerSlice.reducer
```

**store.js :**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import colorizerReducer from './reducers/colorPick'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    colorizer: colorizerReducer,
  }
})
```

**App.js :**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Notes from './screens/Notes';
import ViewNote from './screens/ViewNote';
import EditNote from './screens/EditNote';
import AddNote from './screens/AddNote';
import store from './redux/store';

export default function App() {
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={defaultOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen name='Notes' component={Notes} options={notesOptions} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ViewNote' component={ViewNote} options={viewNotesOptions} />
        <Stack.Screen name='EditNote' component={EditNote} options={editNotesOptions} />
        <Stack.Screen name='AddNote' component={AddNote} options={addNotesOptions} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**ColorPalette.js :** (I can read my state in this component)

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { green, red, yellow, orange, pink } from '../redux/reducers/colorPick'

const ColorPalette = () => {
  const { color } = useSelector((state) => state.colorizer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(color.nav);
  return (
    <View style={styles.paletteContainer}>
      <Pressable style={[styles.color, {backgroundColor: '#ffed27'}]} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => dispatch(yellow())} />
      <Pressable style={[styles.color, {backgroundColor: '#ff3d27'}]} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => dispatch(red())} />
      <Pressable style={[styles.color, {backgroundColor: '#4bff27'}]} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => dispatch(green())} />
      <Pressable style={[styles.color, {backgroundColor: '#ff27fb'}]} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => dispatch(pink())} />
      <Pressable style={[styles.color, {backgroundColor: '#ff8527'}]} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => dispatch(orange())} />
      <View style={{backgroundColor: color.nav, width:20}}></View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: color.bg, width:20}}></View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**NoteTile.js :** (I cannot read in this component)

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const NoteTile = ({title, det, pressFunc}) => {
    const { color } = useSelector((state) => state.colorizer);
    // const color = useSelector((state) => state.colorizer.color);
  return (
    <View style={styles.tileContainer} >
        <Pressable  android_ripple={{color: '#cccccc'}} 
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={pressFunc} >
            <View style={[styles.innerContainer]} >
                <Text style={styles.title} >{title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.details} >{det}</Text>
            </View>
        </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}

export default NoteTile

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tileContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 10,
        height: 100,
        maxHeight: 400,
        borderRadius: 30,
        elevation: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        // backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
        backgroundColor: color.bg,
    }})
```

The error that I got is 'Can't find variable: color'

I wrapped my code with Provider.
And I use NoteTile.js in Notes Screen which is within the Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using it this way

```
<View style={[styles.tileContainer,{ backgroundColor:color.bg }]} >
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your answer. I'm genuinely surprised. Can you enlighten me on why it worked?

Comment: `color` is out of scope in the StyleSheet - it's only available in the component where you called useSelector. By applying the style inside the component, you keep the variable in scope.